# How to filter results based on node property in Cypher

Tags: cypher

Can someone please assist me on how to write a query that will return the following:
"List the titles of all movies with a review with at most 3 stars."
OUTPUT: movie title.

using this database
https://neo4j.com/developer/movie-database/

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: MATCH (m:Movie) \n RETURN m.movie ORDER BY s:stars \n LIMIT 3 ASC

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WHERE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/) to filter results.

```
MATCH (m:Movie) WHERE m.starts>=3 RETURN m.movie
```

Also see

- [operators](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/operators/#query-operators-comparison)